# A subset of trigonometric polynomials is dense in continuous periodic functions

Tags: metric-spaces, periodic-functions

Let $$S=\left\{\sin(nx):2\leq n\in\mathbb N\right\}\cup\left\{\cos(nx):0\leq n\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$ i.e. the standard basis for all trig. polynomials excluding $\sin(1\cdot x)$. By Fejer's theorem, if we included $\sin(x)$, then $span(S)$ would have been dense in $C_{per}[-\pi,\pi]$ , i.e real continuous functions with $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$.

But is $span(S)$ with the above definition dense in $C_{per}[-\pi,\pi]$? The relevant norm is $$||f||_\infty=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in[-\pi,\pi]\}$$

Also, I should note that this proof needs to avoid Fourier related stuff.

I thought maybe to use Stone-Weierstrass:

- obviously $[-\pi,\pi]$ is compact,
- (I think) $span(S)$ forms an algebra,
- $span(S)$ separates points, and
- $1=\cos(0\cdot x)\in span(S)$.

So it should be dense... But somehow I don't feel comfortable with this proof.

First, I'm not entirely sure $span(S)$ forms an algebra, specifically being closed to multiplication. Second, is there a way to better illustrate how is it that for every continuous function $f$ there exists a trigonometric polynomial close as desired to $f$ given the above norm? How about $\sin(x)$ that has been excluded in $S$?

And in general, if $span(S)$ is indeed dense, is there a constructive way to generate smaller subsets that are also dense in $C_{per}[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: How close $span(S)$ can approximate $\sin x$?

Comment: This is one thing I wasn't able to do... and for the same reason I'm not sure it forms an algebra. Is there anything more intelligent that can be done instead of crunching trigonometric identities and taylor expansions?

Answer (score 0):

This set is not an algebra.  I think the easiest way to show that is to show that the span is not dense; hence, we know that some assumption of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem fails, and you already checked the rest of them.

If span is dense, then $\sin x$ can be approximated within $\epsilon$ by some linear combination of $\sin nx$, $n\ge 2$, and $\cos nx$. Let $f$ be this linear combination, so that $|f(x)-\sin x|<\epsilon$. Then 
$$f(x)\sin x> \sin^2x - \epsilon|\sin x|$$
hence 
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin x \,dx > \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin^2 x \,dx 
- \epsilon \int_{-\pi}^\pi |\sin x |\,dx  = \pi - 2\epsilon  
$$
which is strictly positive when $\epsilon$ is small enough.

On the other hand, $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin x \,dx=0$ because $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin nx \sin x \,dx=0$ for $n\ge 2$ (use trig identities), and $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos nx \sin x \,dx=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ (notice the integrand is odd). A contradiction.